# Remove Zend Form error messages

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

How to remove Zend Form error mesessages (Value is required and can't be empty) ?

Comment: You need to remove error decorators or validators.

Comment: I need to remove this message Value is required and can't be empty

Comment: But you want to keep other messages? If no, remove the error decorator. If yes, remove the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
$element->setRequired(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$yourElement->removeDecorator('Errors');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite error messages in the form like in this example:

```
    $this->addElement('text', Model_User_Object::USERNAME, array(
        'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('notEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'isEmpty' => 'YOU CAN WRITE WHATEVER MESSAGE YOU WANT HERE.'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'input',
        'label' => 'Your username:',
    ));
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to use this: exp. addValidator(new Application_Validate_Email())

Comment: You can do it both ways, however I'm pretty sure your way can't overwrite error messages.